# A socket gets delayed from queue after awhile

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, select, concurrent-collections

am trying to use `Socket.Select` in multi-threaded application , and I don't wanna use `async socket` , so here is my code :-

```
 public class Server {
        private TcpListener m_listener;
        private IConnectionFactory m_factory;
        private List<Socket> Sockets = new List<Socket>();
        private ConcurrentDictionary<Socket, Connection> Clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<Socket, Connection>();
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<Socket>> Threads = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<Socket>>();
        private int maxsockets = 0;
        private object sync = new object();

        public Server(string ip, int port, IConnectionFactory factory, int maxsockets) {
            IPAddress ipa = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipa, port);
            this.maxsockets = maxsockets;
            m_listener = listener;
            m_factory = factory;

            int threads = maxsockets <= 100 ? 1 : maxsockets / 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
                Thread th = new Thread(HandelSockets);
                th.Name = i.ToString();
                Threads.TryAdd(i.ToString(), new ConcurrentQueue<Socket>());
                th.Start();
            }
        }

        public void HandelSockets() {
            ConcurrentQueue<Socket> queue = Threads[Thread.CurrentThread.Name];
            Connection temp;
            Socket sock;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    lock (sync) {
                        while (queue.TryDequeue(out sock)) {
                            if (Clients.TryGetValue(sock, out temp)) {
                                if (!temp.Alive) {
                                    Sockets.Remove(sock);
                                    Clients.TryRemove(sock, out temp);
                                } else {
                                    temp.Receive();
                                    Console.WriteLine("recved from thread num : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch { }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        public void Run() {
            m_listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("listen started");
            Sockets.Add(m_listener.Server);

            while (true) {
                try {
                    var temp_list = Sockets.ToList();
                    Socket.Select(temp_list, null, null, 1000);

                    foreach (Socket socket in temp_list) {
                        if (socket == m_listener.Server) {

                            var sock = m_listener.AcceptSocket();
                            Sockets.Add(sock);
                            Connection conn = m_factory.Create(sock);
                            Clients.TryAdd(sock, conn);
                        } else if (Clients.Count >= maxsockets) {
                            Clients[socket].OnMaxConnections();
                            break;
                        } else {
                            if (!Threads.Values.Any(x => x.Contains(socket))) {
                                var quque = Threads.Values.Where(x => !x.Contains(socket)).OrderBy(x => x.Count).First();
                                lock (sync) {
                                    quque.Enqueue(socket);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

problem is after a while one of the connected sockets will be delayed , one of the sockets will stop sending or receiving until one of the other sockets do so!, or it might take a few secs/minutes until it comeback to receive and send!

I have no clue why would that happen!? maybe the way I select a queue with? , I hope someone can point me to what could make that delay happen thanks.

Comment: Seems to me like you're doing a whole bunch of work in a loop looking for socket connections (hence why you added `Thread.Sleep(1)`).  that *could* overload the CPU enough to cause a blip in receiving/sending.  Why manage a queue of connections when you can simply do it with async sockets?  e.g. you've shown about 85 lines of code and you're still not doing anything with sending/receiving data. Those 85 could be done in about 5 with async sockets.

Answer (score 0):

```
lock (sync) {
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out sock)) {
        if (Clients.TryGetValue(sock, out temp)) {
            if (!temp.Alive) {
                Sockets.Remove(sock);
                Clients.TryRemove(sock, out temp);
            } else {
                temp.Receive();
                Console.WriteLine("recved from thread num : " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see your implementation of Connection.Receive but if it's a blocking call i.e. doesn't return until it has received data, then that thread would be holding onto a lock on the `sync` object which is causing your other threads to wait and therefore causing the delay.

Now that you know what is causing the problem you can make the necessary changes, however i highly recommend you use the async methods as it'll perform better and remove the need for locking entirely.

Edit: oh i just realised this is an old question

Comment: thnx for your reply I will conisder what you just told me , am still trying to fix it tho 0.0